# R - dplyr left_join() - Multiple Matches - How to Recombine...?

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have the following:

```
x <- data.frame(
       Row_Index = 1:5,
       Name = c("Alan", "Bob", "Charles", "David", "Eric"),
       Age = c(49, 23, 44, 52, 18),
       City = c("London", "Paris", "Berlin", "Moscow", "Tokyo")
)

y <- data.frame(
       Claim_Reference = 1:6,
       Row_Index = c(3, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4),
       Claim_Amount = c(100, 1000, 500, 200, 300, 5000)
)

z <- x %>% left_join(y, by = c("Row_Index" = "Row_Index")) %>%
           group_by (Row_Index, Name, Age) %>%
           summarise(Total_Claim_Amount = sum(Claim_Amount))
```

it produces a nice joined table where for each individual in `x` I can see their `Name`, `Age` and `Total_Claim_Amount`. All ok.

It would be sufficient for grouping purposes to use `Row_Index` alone in the `group_by()` statement and skip `Name` and `Age`, but then they won't appear in the resulting table, which isn't what I want.

In a real life example, I'm doing exactly the same type of lookup, but with many more fields. my left join query has 55 variables inside the `group_by()` statement and 16 variables inside the `summarise()` statement. It's overwhelming my PC.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? It's something I need to do quite often. Should I, for example, move the "redundant" variables in the `group_by()` statement into the summarise statement, preceded by a `first()` or something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your desired output for this example?

Comment: z is exactly what I want to see as output. My only problem is that preparing z this way doesn't scale well if I have lots and lots of fields to work with.

Comment: In this example, none of the grouping variables add more groups than the `row_index`. One could think of it that the `row_index` defines a row, and `Name`, `Age`, potentially your other grouping variables, are essentially contextual labels for the groups. If this is the case in your real data, it will be **much** faster to summarize the small table and then join, rather than join, creating a very big table, and then summarize.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is correct re "contextual labels" - once I have grouped by Row_Index, adding these other variables won't create extra groups.

I will try the approach you suggested shortly...

Comment: So `z <- y %>% group_by(Row_index) %>% summarize(...) %>% right_join(x, by = "Row_index")` will give the same result much more efficiently.

Comment: Well to skip `Name` and `Age` in your `group_by()` you can change your summarize function like this: ```summarise(Name = Name[1], Age = Age[1], Total_Claim_Amount = sum(Claim_Amount))``` but how to scale this to your actual data, it's not clear to me what causes the problem. I would switch to `data.table` package as it generally handles large datasets better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z <- y %>% 
  group_by(Row_index) %>%
  summarize(...) %>% 
  right_join(x, by = "Row_index")
# same result, much more efficiently.
```

In your example, you add a bunch of columns to `y` with the join, 55 columns, with lots of repeated information. Grouping by and summarizing all those columns means R has to go through every single column and make sure there aren't any mismatches with `row_index` that would require the creation of a new group. You *know* that each `row_index` defines a group, so you should tell R to group only by `row_index`, do your summarize, and then do the join to add contextual information for each `row_index`. This should be exponentially faster with the number of columns.

If you want additional speed, you could switch to `data.table`, but my guess is this will adequately solve your speed problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply in such detail - very useful for me to know.

Comment: Done...the query now runs in about 15 seconds (previously ran for about half an hour before crashing!). Thanks again